# How to prevent automatic link preview generation for status update in Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am [using Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) to post status updates programmatically.
However, when my status contains a link, Twitter automatically adds the preview for that link. Sometimes it's not the desired behaviour, however, I didn't find a property in the API to disable it.

I know we can remove the link preview when posting manually via the Twitter website, as described here [Remove Preview Image when Posting a Link on Twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113760/remove-preview-image-when-posting-a-link-on-twitter), so I suspect that it's possible, but API never mentions it.

Also, I am using `tweepy` library for Python, but happy to resort to the raw `POST` if that solves my problem.

Any ideas what should I add to the request to prevent the link preview generation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually tried to post to Twitter manually on the web, twice:

1. With the generated link preview
2. Explicitly removing the preview (clicking the cross button once the preview is generated)

While doing it, I observed the payload that the website sends to the Twitter servers (with Chrome Dev Tools).

And interestingly enough, the only difference between these two tweets was only one property: `card_uri: tombstone://card`. More specifically, **this property was present in the tweet without the preview**.

After that, I actually tried to go and add `card_uri` property to my status update request, and it actually did the job: the preview was not automatically rendered.

Conviniently, `tweepy` library has an optional `card_uri` argument in the `update_status` menthod.

To sum up, you need to set `card_uri='tombstone://card'` in your request to prevent Twitter from autogenerating the link previews.

*Unfortunately, I didn't find any references to this in the API (or in Google at all), so I am not confident that this is a long-lasting solution, but that's at least something to start with.*